# Share Image from Gallery after selected into facebook using Facebook sdk v4.x

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to share my Image from Gallery to facebook after selected, I'm using Facebook sdk v4.0. Here is my code, I don't know why Bitmap in postPhoto() still null but the fileUri in pickImage() already have file path.

This is pick image Intent

```
 private void pickImage() {
    Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

After that I named the fileUri

```
 public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Next, I have postPhoto() that I can share photo using facebook sdk

```
private void onClickPostPhoto() {
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);
}

private void postPhoto() {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath()); //>>>bitmap still null PLEAS HELP!!!
    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
    ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    photos.add(sharePhoto);

    SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
            new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).build();
    if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
        shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
    } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
    } else {
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
    }


}
```

Finally, I got my onActivityForResult

```
  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //******Camera********
    if(requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.d("TAG" + ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", picturePath);
            cursor.close();
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(picturePath));
        onClickPostPhoto();
```

Finally, after couple hours. I fixed it, see my edit above at the onActivityForResult.

Comment: if you have fixed it yourself, please consider writing an answer to your own question, and then removing the answer from the "question" section. That will make things a lot clearer for others who are having the same problem.

Comment: thanks for your advices